# Getting started with Google Calendar for C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am totally new to Google API and have no experience integrating things into my programs. Now I am assigned to work on integrating the calendar into my program. Unfortunately I cannot find good tutorials and I don't know where to place the codes that Google placed at the developer guide at. Now I am totally clueless. Please help. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of information on the Calendar API and the .NET library in our [APIs wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Calendar_API). I think you should  also take a look in our OAuth2 wiki page [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2). Last thing - take a look in our [samples repository](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples) (unfortunately we don't have a sample for Calendar API) for samples of Google APIs like Tasks, Books, etc.